# expects catch() or return even after returning the result

Tags: node.js, promise, eslint

sorry for asking a silly question but I have returned everything in the the given code but still it says

```
52:5   error    Expected catch() or return      promise/catch-or-return
```

I don't know what its expecting.this is my code.

```
52:5    rp(options).then(function (response,body) {
            a = response.data;
            return a;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            // POST failed...
            return console.log('error');

        }).then(result =>{
           console.log('key: ' + a);
           return db.collection('Users').doc(user_id).set({name:name1,notification_key:a,image:image1,token_id:token_id1,email:token_email});
});
```

Comment: For starters, this `.then(function (response,body)` is wrong.  `.then()` only passes ONE parameter to its function.

Comment: For more help, you will probably have to show us the context this code is contained within.  It appears your error might be telling you that you aren't either .catching the last promise in your code or returning it for someone else to `.catch()` it so you have a potentially unhandled rejection.  Also, your use of `a` which is not declared in this code looks problematic.

Comment: `return rp(options).~`

Comment: Not returning a promise from a function is a common mistake. This linter rule addresses it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a linter error (eslint rule `promise/catch-or-return`). It's meant to avoid unhandled rejections and promises.

The problem with line `52` is most likely that the full code is:

```
function myFunction() {
   /* ... */      
   rp().then(/*.*/).catch(/*.*/).then(/*.*/);
}
```

You are not handling the promise, so either you add a `catch()` after the final `then` or return the whole promise with `return rp()`.